# Store data in Tx Metadata on Cardano

Tags: transaction, metadata, transaction-metadata

I would like to notarize some data (like document signatures for example) of less than 500KB on the blockchain and for that I thought to use the Metadata field of a transaction.

So I have 2 questions:

1. Is this a good (or at least acceptable) use of this field?
2. Is it better to do it on Cardano directly or wait for the release of an L2 like Hydra?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, transactions on Cardano are limited to a maximum of 16k so you probably wouldn't want to store the document directly onto the blockchain.  That said, you might want to consider storing the document onto something like an IPFS and then referencing the signed document from the metadata.

As for waiting for Hydra, while Hydra may change the fees and throughput associated with the transaction, I imagine the solution would be the same.